# Haml breaking. Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am still unclear about why this breaks:

```
.form-box
      %h3 Restrictions
      %legend Restricted Locations
        = form_for [:blueadmin, :wine, @wine], html: {class: 'form-horizontal col-lg-2'} do |f|
          %fieldset.inputs
            .control-group
              = f.label :us_states, "US States", class: 'control-label'
              .controls
                = f.collection_select :product, Restriction.all, :us_state, :us_state, {}, :multiple => 'true'
          %fieldset
            %ol
              %li.button
                = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary'
      %table.table.table-hover.table-condensed.story-list
        %th State
        %th Remove
```

The error I get is: 
`Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %legend and nested within it.`

the `= form_for` seems to be the culprit

I understand Restricted Location is on the same line as %legend... but that's how I see the docs.

This works though, but it screws up my legend border:

```
  .form-box
      %h3 Restrictions
      %legend
        Restricted Locations
        = form_for [:blueadmin, :wine, @wine], html: {class: 'form-horizontal col-lg-2'} do |f|
          %fieldset.inputs
            .control-group
              = f.label :us_states, "US States", class: 'control-label'
              .controls
                = f.collection_select :product, Restriction.all, :us_state, :us_state, {}, :multiple => 'true'
          %fieldset
            %ol
              %li.button
                = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary'
    %table.table.table-hover.table-condensed.story-list
      %th State
      %th Remove
```

It looks like this:

[image]

instead of this:
[image]

(notice how the thin line is in a different spot)

Lastly, how do I get the table on the bottom to appear to the right of the form and not underneath? How can I use columns to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure you should do `= form_for`. Whenever I use a `form_for` in haml, it's `- form_for`.

Answer (score 1):

you have your form for nested inside the legend element.

```
 .form-box
  %h3 Restrictions
  %legend
    Restricted Locations
  = form_for [:blueadmin, :wine, @wine], html: {class: 'form-horizontal col-lg-2'} do |f|
    %fieldset.inputs
      .control-group
        = f.label :us_states, "US States", class: 'control-label'
        .controls
          = f.collection_select :product, Restriction.all, :us_state, :us_state, {}, :multiple => 'true'
    %fieldset
      %ol
        %li.button
          = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary'
%table.table.table-hover.table-condensed.story-list
  %th State
  %th Remove
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the form out of `%legend` tag.

Change the code to this:

```
.form-box
  %h3 Restrictions
  %legend 
    Restricted Locations
  = form_for [:blueadmin, :wine, @wine], html: {class: 'form-horizontal col-lg-2'} do |f|
    %fieldset.inputs
      .control-group
        = f.label :us_states, "US States", class: 'control-label'
        .controls
          = f.collection_select :product, Restriction.all, :us_state, :us_state, {}, :multiple => 'true'
    %fieldset
      %ol
        %li.button
          = f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary'
  %table.table.table-hover.table-condensed.story-list
    %th State
    %th Remove
```

Use inline content only if you have single element to nest. In your case you are trying to nest  `Restricted Locations` text as well as `form`

**Note:** HAML works on indentation so any changes in indentation results in different html code or syntax error